# Which options should be used in order to generate Trailer accessible route?

Tags: here-api, heremaps-ios-sdk

Want to generate a trailer accessible route for car+trailer(towed).
Currently in *NMARoutingMode*, when the *transportMode* is car, we don't get any trailer or vehicle length options.
What routingMode options should be used to generate a route for the above?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do support Truck with Trailer Routing in NMARoutingMode, that can suffix your requirement.

The NMARoutingMode class contains truck-specific properties that you should set to perform a route calculation. You need to set the route transportation mode to NMATransportModeTruck and then optionally set the following route properties before launching the calculation:
The number of truck trailers
The truck height
The truck length
The truck width
The maximum allowed truck weight
The category of tunnels that the truck cannot travel on
The truck weight per axle
Hazardous goods that are transported by the truck
Difficult turns

```
Where you can pass the following - 

routingMode.vehicleLength = 25.25f;
routingMode.vehicleHeight = 2.6f;
routingMode.trailersCount = 1;
```